# How to use CandleStick series type in AnyChart Android?

Tags: android, anychart

I'm using AnyChart lib for android, but i can't find CandleStick series type by default. I think I need custom a Plot by my sefl and add that chart type. Can anyone give me an example of custom plot in any chart android ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in the current version of the library, the candlestick series constructor is not implemented.
But there's a trick that allows creating candlestick series. Check the code below:

```
        AnyChartView anyChartView = findViewById(R.id.any_chart_view);

    Table table = Table.instantiate("x");
    table.addData(getData());

    TableMapping mapping = table.mapAs("{open: 'open', high: 'high', low: 'low', close: 'close'}");

    Stock stock = AnyChart.stock();

    Plot plot = stock.plot(0);

    plot.defaultSeriesType("candlestick");
    plot.addSeries(mapping);

    anyChartView.setChart(stock);
```

Comment: is there any chance to change the color of the candlesticks ?

Comment: Try the fallingFill() and risingFill() functions of the series

Comment: I'm not seeing that in Android library. Is there any snippet available for that ?

Comment: Like this:
plot.defaultSeriesType("candlestick");
plot.addSeries(mapping);
Candlestick series = (Candlestick) plot.getSeries(0);
series.risingFill(new String[]{"red"});
series.fallingFill(new String[]{"blue"});